# Does deleting an MO account delete other StackExchange accounts?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, stackexchange

If a user deletes their account on MO will all the associated accounts on other StackExchange sites be deleted as well?

Comment: From what I saw on MSE, the answer is no. You can safely delete just one profile.

Comment: I agree.  I deleted one of my SE accounts and the others were not affected.

Comment: I can confirm what Joel says.  I believe I created an economics or quant SE account and deleted it shortly after with no affect on my other accounts.

Comment: I hope you are not considering to delete *your* MO-account for some reason.

Comment: @quid: I have no plans to stop using MO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the other accounts would remain unless the user also requests that they are deleted, through those other accounts.  Some have already commented with their experience seeing this happen on other sites, and [this authoritative answer on meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7979/) confirms that an account deletion requested on one SE site affects only the account on that specific site.